# Display the query if the number of equal vertex is at least 1 (let blocks)

Tags: orientdb

I actually have this query but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT expand($Result)
let $Cri = (
  SELECT *
  FROM Cri
  WHERE libelle = "abbaye"
),
$Ontologie = (
  SELECT *
  FROM Ontologie
  WHERE libelle = "BlocModal_3_VISITE"
),
$Result = (
  SELECT *
  FROM $Ontologie
  WHERE $Cri.out().@rid = $Ontologie.out().out().out("Pertinent").@rid
)
```

First, When I execute in differents query :

```
$Ontologie.out().out().out("Pertinent")

$Cri.out()
```

I find the same result so I don't understand why it doesn't work in the let block

Secondly, for the $Result, I want to select every $Ontologie if I have at least one time this expression true :

```
 $Cri.out().@rid = $Ontologie.out().out().("Pertinent").@rid
```

Finally, I know I can't do a WHERE clause because it'll only select the $Ontologie that match with this expression.

I actually have tried with 'IF' but it seems to doesn't work..

Here is my Schema : 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide your db so it's possible to do some tests?... or if you can't do it, could you explain how your db-schema was made?

Comment: I added my Schema !

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with the SECONDAIRE/PERTINENT line and PERTINENT/SYNONYME and FACULTATIF/OBLIGATOIRE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a let is a list and therefore you don't must use = but contains

You could use

```
SELECT expand($Result)
let $Cri = ( SELECT * FROM Cri WHERE libelle = "abbaye"),
$Ontologie = ( SELECT * FROM Ontologie WHERE libelle = "BlocModal_3_VISITE"),
$Result = ( SELECT * FROM $Ontologie WHERE $Cri.out().@rid contains out().out().out().@rid)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you !
I didn't know it was a list, now it works !